# Where are the standard output commands for scheduled jobs logged in Rundeck?

Tags: rundeck

I am trying to analyse the logs of scheduled jobs in a project in Rundeck. When I check the successful logs of a job in the Rundeck GUI, I can see some lines in the *Log Output* tab, however I wish to see where these logs are on the machine.

Here's what I have already tried:

1. I have checked `/var/log/rundeck` after reading some documentation [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/maintenance/logs.html#logs)
2. I have also gone through the script to see if the logs are being logged elsewhere.

The logs I am looking for are standard *print* statements. Where can I find these logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rundeck has two kind of logs, "general logs" (located at `/var/log/rundeck`) and Execution Logs (your question), located at: `/var/lib/rundeck/logs/rundeck/your-project-name/job/your-job-id/logs`.

Those paths exist if you have a DEB/RPM based installation. If you are using a WAR based installation the "general logs" are located in `$RDECK_BASE/server/logs` and Execution Logs at `$RDECK_BASE/var/logs/rundeck/your-project-name/job/your-job-id/logs`.